# лагерь Эльс(,) к северу от Кватча

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Нам известно лишь одно из мест, где прячутся бандиты, — лагерь Эльс(,) к северу от Кватча.

Нужна ли запятая в указанном месте и почему? Эльс – это название лагеря, Кватч – город. Это предложение из компьютерной игры, в переводе запятая стоит, но в нем встречаются ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Нам известно лишь одно из мест, где прячутся бандиты, — лагерь Эльс, **к северу от Кватча.***

Здесь возможны оба варианта, и весьма вероятно, что второе обстоятельство **уточняет** первое и поэтому обособляется в качестве **дополнительных сведений.**

При отсутствии  обособления мы сразу указываем **обе координаты** – сам лагерь и его расположение, считая информацию **одинаково важной** для собеседника.

Соответственно, выбор варианта делается с учетом контекста, то есть конкретной ситуации.

Так обстоит дело в реальности, но и **в компьютерной игре** тот же принцип сохраняется. Если название города игрокам хорошо знакомо, то можно предположить, что второе обстоятельство является именно уточнением. Впрочем, ничего принципиально важного в разной пунктуации здесь нет.

**Примечание** (комментарий к первому ответу)

*Нам известно лишь **однО из мест**, где прячутся бандИты, — **лагерь Эльс, к северу от Кватча.***

1. Неверно определена **грамматика:** обособленный с помощью тире  оборот является **присоединительным**,  он раскрывает значение местоимения «одно» в сочетании "одно из мест". В этом случае ставится и запятая, и тире (классический вариант независимой постановки знаков).
2. По поводу **«выразительной паузы»**

Присоединительное тире  – это всё-таки не двоеточие со значительно увеличенной предупредительной паузой, там пауза короче, но тоже подчеркнутая.

Answer (score 0):

Это неполное предложение с «пропущенным» словом «расположенный» или «находящийся». Если это слово восполнить, то это обычный обособляемый определительный оборот, расположенный после определяемого слова. Тире на месте «пропущенного» слова, конечно же, не ставится, так как такое тире ставится только в случае выразительной паузы, которой здесь нет.